# FullCalendar how to stop select on Inverse Background events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using [FullCalendar JavaScript Event Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) component.

How do I stop users from creating (drag to select) events in the [Inverse Background](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events) (green) areas:

[image]

Method [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) only fires if the user selects on the white area, not the green, so I cannot use this method to stop the selection in the green area.

Method [selectAllow](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow) only gives me access to `selectInfo` which has `start` and `end` and `resourceId` properties, so there is nothing that changes between the white and green that I can evaluate on.

Comment: "I've tried passing the events data to the selectConstraint option "...That would never work. The documentation for selectConstraint points out you can supply the same kind of object as accepted by https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventConstraint , which explains quite clearly the structure it recognises.

Comment: what you could do is build your selectConstraint object _based on_ your event data, if it's simply enough to fit into that model. If not, then you'll have to write some custom code for selectOverlap, there's a simple example given in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap, but you could write something which got hold of all the event data (using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/clientEvents) and looped through them, to see if the selected area overlaps any of them. Note that since you're using inverse background events, you'd only be allowing selections which fit _within_ the event times

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the `selectAllow` method and looping over the the `clientEvents`

```
selectAllow : function(selectInfo) 
{               
     var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt) 
     {
         return (evt.start <= selectInfo.start 
                 && evt.end >= selectInfo.end 
                 && evt.resourceId == selectInfo.resourceId);
     });               

     return events.length > 0;
},
```